# Linq where keyword vs. Where extension and Expression parameters

Tags: linq, delegates, extension-methods

Passing in an Expression to a Linq query behaves differently depending on syntax used, and I wonder why this is the case.

Let's say I have this very generic function

```
private IEnumerable<Company> 
    GetCompanies(Expression<Func<Company, bool>> whereClause)
```

The following implementation works as expected

```
private IEnumerable<Company> 
    GetCompanies(Expression<Func<Company, bool>> whereClause)
{
    return (from c in _ctx.Companies.Where(whereClause) select c);
}
```

But this next implementation does not compile
(Delegate 'System.Func' does not take 1 arguments)

```
private IEnumerable<Company> 
    GetCompanies(Expression<Func<Company, bool>> whereClause)
{
    return (from c in _ctx.Companies where whereClause select c);
}
```

Obviously I can just use the first syntax, but I was just wondering why the compiler does not treat the where keyword the same as the Where extension?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for a query expression involving a `where` clause is (simplifying the complete grammar)

```
from identifier in expression where boolean-expression select expression
```

`whereClause` is not a boolean expression. To recitify this, you have to say

```
from c in _ctx.Companies where whereClause.Compile()(c) select c;
```

Note that if `whereClause` were a `Func<Company, bool>` you could get away with

```
from c in _ctx.Companies where whereClause(c) select c;
```

Note that

```
from x in e where f
```

is translated mechanically by the compiler into

```
(from x in e).Where(x => f)
```

I say mechanically because it performs this translation without doing any semantic analysis to check validity of the method calls etc. That stage comes later after all query expressions have been translated to LINQ method-invocation expressions.

In particular,

```
from c in _ctx.Companies where whereClause select c
```

is translated to

```
_ctx.Companies.Where(c => whereClause).Select(c)
```

which is clearly nonsensical.

The reason that

```
from c in _ctx.Companies.Where(whereClause) select c
```

is legit is because `IEnumerable<Company>.Where` has an overload accepting a `Func<Company, bool>` and there is an implicit conversion from an `Expression<Func<Company, bool>>` to a `Func<Company, bool>`.

Comment: If you were to accept Func<Company, bool> as an argument instead of Expression<Func<Company, bool>>, then you could have used Predicate<Company> as the parameter type.

Comment: Yeah this is a simplified example only to focus on the 'where' differences. The reason for using a Expression<Func<Company, bool>> is that I would want the where to be executed on the data base and not in memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually shorten the whole thing to:

```
private IEnumerable<Company> 
    GetCompanies(Expression<Func<Company, bool>> whereClause)
{
    return _ctx.Companies.Where(whereClause);
}
```

When you use the LINQ syntax, the code in the `where` clause is translated into an `Expression<>`, which represents a code tree. When you accept `Expression<Func<Customer, bool>>`, you are saying that your method accepts a code tree, which is converted from C# code by the compiler.

Since you already have the code tree, you have to pass it directly to the `Where()` method, rather than using LINQ syntax.

Comment: Yes I do realize that, my example was made to spell out where the difference occurs, i.e. where vs. .Where.
Thanks though :).

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in sql-like where it expects expression that evaluates to bool. But in Where method the type of expression can be the delegate.

to force second to work you can change to `whereClause.Compile()(c)` or change parameter to `Func<Company, bool> whereClause` and `whereClause(c)`